build C++ program by qmake,nmake in windows11 ,but can not run
My C++ program source code at work is build with Qt5 on Windows 11(cross platform code, linux works well), which contains several project and all belong to One software of my company.I have question about how to build them. The older nerd tell me build them with Qt command qmake and nmake and it does work ,the *.exe and *.dll files came out.
But When I run them in Win11 console, every application works well but ONE.it say "This application cannot run on your computer". Then I rebuild this one with VS2019(vsxproj file generated by "qmake -t vcapp" with .pro file),turns out it works well.(Dose not use QtCeator).
I try a lot to fix that ,but I do not have any clue, and this problem last for months. What do I need to do next?(Forgive my English is not good at all)
What do I need to do next? Or is something wrong with source code?



I'd guess that you're missing a dll from the runtime path. Have you tried using a debugger? Please show the exact error message

environment variables setting is fine ，I'm sure library or dll or platform is right. whether compile  with qmake or  vs2019,the bin path does not change. message upload ,sorry about my leaders ask me to cover it. hope I upload pic in right way.

Please don't post images of error messages, especially when they're not in English, post the text instead

it has two error message  first one means “access denied” or "permission denied".second  one means "cant run this app on your computer"

The problem has been solved ，thanks very much.

When building this with QT-Creator you need to make sure that you are using the correct toolset. For this dedicated one you worked wih the wron toolset. To fix this you need to build it with VS2019 when this is your compiler for Windows 11.
You can do this via qmake or just in  QtCreator: select the right toolset for VS2019 in your configuration.

Thanks for your answer，But we never use QT-Creator as IDE, just code with VS2019 and manage project with qt pro file. When compile code with qmake and nmake in console or vs2019 ，normaly they works from both way，Just the special exe file can not run after qmake nmake compile . I'm very curious what went wrong with it.

There are two options when it is not running: false compiler or not all dependenciew were load correctly. You can try to open th e exe with depends to chech if a dependenciy is missing.

depends show same result , two exe files share same bin path and library path and environment variables. even .vcxproj file came from "qmake -t vcapp" command. So I wonder what different between vs2019 and qmake(QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc)，why this   program can only compiler on vs2019 . how can I compiler right with qmake  ?

32 bit or 64 bit?

it goes 64 bit.

Maybe 32 / 62 bit conflict?

pretty sure both exe file is 64 bit，because I view the exe file with hex model and I see “54 45 00 00 64” (base on the Internet way check file is 64 bit or not)
